# Is an HTML polygon iframe possible?

Tags: html, css, iframe, popup, polygon

I plan on making a popup for information. I though it would be cool to have something like this:

[image: Parallelogram iframe]

but I don't know any way it could be made. **Is it possible at all?** Because if not I'll use some other way..
Popup, darken background, close and fullscreen (=redirection to full page) won't be too hard but if it's possible, **what about the scrollbar?**

Answer (score 2):

No, its not possible with native html at all.

But you can use a lot of java script and css to try to find something similar.
There is a example that I found on the web

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      iframe#myframe {
        -ms-transform: skewY(20deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: skewY(20deg); /* Safari */
        transform: skewY(20deg); /* Standard syntax */
        overflow: scroll
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe id=myframe src="http://www.mozilla.org"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Maybe you can tried to use this one.

Comment: I know it won't be easy :D Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try CSS3 2D Transform
example here:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transform_skewy

Add a overflow:scroll to the skewed div should give you the scrollbar.

Comment: Thanks for the hint!